# how to use VLOOKUP like from Excel in Tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api, vlookup, lookup

Im new in Tableau and want to analyze some data where i need to reference to values in the same table. I have no idea how to do this. 
I take a look at LOOKUP but dont get it.

Here is the requirement: I need to check if values in `C` from line/dataset `123-02` are the same as in line/dataset `123`

```
  A   |    B     |    C    
------|----------|-----------------|
  TP  |  Value   | expected result | 
------|----------|-----------------|  
123   | abc      | abc             | 
123-01| abc      | abc             | 
123-02| thgfs    | abc             | 
123-03| pro      | abc             | 
155   | qwert    | qwert           | 
155-01| abc      | qwert           | 
155-02| uztre 3  | qwert           |
```

I got this expected results in Excel with this formula in column `C`:  `VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2;3);A:B;2;FALSE)`. Means: Take the first three char from `A`, search the entry which has exactly this three char in column A, got to column `B` and give me this value in the same line.

How can i get this in Tableau? I Need to do this for 500.000 datasets (or maybe a bit more, 1Mio or 2Mio).

Comment: so you want to take all entries/rows in column A that are strictly "123" and return what's in column b for these for these rows?

Comment: yes, i want at all entries which begin with `123` the value from dataset `123` which is `abc` (in column B). I made the examples a bit better, i hope. I need this to find wrong entries in the datatsets. The dataset with `abc` or `155` is the leading dataset and has to give the values for all his 'child'-datasets. I know there are Solutions for a better data structure, but i cant Change this structure.

Comment: You need to look up how to use table blends or joins: that is how Tableau handles this (much more powerfully than lookup, BTW).

Comment: I think i know what you mean, thanks. But blending expects two tables. i have just one.   Is it possible to create a 'virtual table' from an existing table? The virtual table (which exist just inside Tableau) needs to get automatically updated if the sources gets new data.

Comment: @enrico If you know you are going to do this, I would organise the data differently up front. But if you want to solve the problem without that step then load the same table *twice* and blend or join to itself. Another way would be to write a simple formula to check the equality of two columns.